# Why artisan throws sql "table already exists" on a non existing table

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

This is my migration file

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateSessionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id')->unique();
            $table->text('payload');
            $table->integer('last_activity');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('sessions');
    }
}
```

It was created when i ran

```
php artisan session:table
```

The database connection is correctly configured since the project is writing and reading from it without problem.

From the root directory of my project i run

```
php artisan migrate
```

And i get the following error messages

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                                                            
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'sessions' already exists (SQL: create table `sessions` (`id` varchar(255) not null,  `payload` text not null, `last_activity` int not null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)

[PDOException]                                                                            
SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'sessions' already exists
```

I know i should run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

But i've tried with and without it and i got the same results. 
I've also tried the Blueprint type before the $table argument.

It bahaves as if it was accessing some different database than the one it uses when i ran the project

Comment: By the way. I forgot to mention that there is no table called "sessions" in my database

Comment: And Do you have only one single file for this migration?

Comment: You could try swapping the contents of up and down.  Run migrate again.  Swap the code back, run migrate:rollback, and migrate again.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the migration if you haven't added data in it. Or do php artisan migrate:rollback.Then php artisan config:clear and then restart your server. Then rerun the migration

Comment: But i can not restart the server because it's a shared host.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue with:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```